# htaccess: show 404 when page is not present

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have following in my htaccess file,

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule ^terms/ /terms.php [QSA]
    </IfModule>

    ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found.php
```

I wnat when user enter url `http://example.com/terms/` then `terms.php` page will be shown, and when user will type something like `http://example.com/terms/kjhkhk` then it should show 404 error.

My first condition to redirect /terms/ to terms.php is working but `http://example.com/terms/` to redirect this url to 404 isn't.

Please help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the rule to be

`^terms\/$`

You may not need the `\/`.

Comment: I wanted to know one more thing, why we have used $ here, is it required? It works as an ending sign for rule, or what? If you aware with any basic doc which can explain the rules to me, then it will be helpful to understand things. Thanks!

Comment: Without `\/` its not working, don't know why. `^terms$` this isn't working.